# Is this interpretation of $\psi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi a^{3}}}e^{-r/a}$ correct?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, wavefunction

Apologies if this is stating the obvious, but I'm a non-physicist trying to understand Griffiths' discussion of the hydrogen atom in chapter 4 of Introduction to Quantum Mechanics. The wave equation for the ground state (I believe) is:$$\psi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi a^{3}}}e^{-r/a}$$

where $a$ is the Bohr radius $0.529\times10^{-10}$m. If I integrate the square of this equation between $r=0$ and $r=x$, am I right in assuming I am calculating the probability of finding the electron in a sphere radius $x$? I've done this for $x=1\textrm{ m}$ and $x=\infty$ and got the answer $1$ (I guess a two metre diameter sphere is pretty big compared to a hydrogen atom). For $x=9\times10^{-11}\textrm{ m}$, the answer is $0.66077$. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: Relevant - http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34095/why-is-wave-function-so-important/40769#40769

Comment: You're interpretation is exactly right. The integral of $|\psi (x)|^2$ from $0$ to $x$ will give you the probability that the particle is in that region.The reason you get a probability of $1$ is because $a$ is really really small, so the exponential falls of quite quickly. If you calculate with enough precision, you'll find the answer to be just slightly less that one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you are wrong. Particular for the following statement:

> If I integrate the square of this equation between $r=0$ and $r=x$, am I right in assuming I am calculating the probability of finding the electron in a sphere radius x?

The probability density at any points is given by $|\psi(r,\theta,\phi)|^2$. Certainly, the probability is for any region $V$ is given by
$$P=\int_V|\psi|^2 dxdydz$$
However, if you are considering a sphere of radius $R$, you should change [the integral into the spherical coordinate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Integration_and_differentiation_in_spherical_coordinates) using the relation $dxdydz=r^2 \sin(\theta)drd\theta d\phi$ as follow
$$P(R)=\int_V|\psi|^2 dxdydz=\int_0^R \int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\pi}  |\psi|^2 r^2 \sin(\theta) dr d\theta d\phi = 4\pi \int_0^R r^2|\psi|^2 dr$$
Note that there is an extra $r^2$ in the equation and an extra constant $4 \pi$. Simply integrate the $|\psi|^2$ from $0$ to $R$ is wrong. It is very easy to check that this integral lead to the normalization condition of the wavefunction, i.e. $P(R\to\infty)=1$.

Comment: From his question it is not clear whether he integrates over the volume $dV$ or over the radius $dr$. We suppose he does it correctly, following the textbook.

Comment: I cut a few corners in my question and have now been found out. My original calculation of the probability $P$
  of finding the electron in a sphere radius $x$
  was along the lines of $$P=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{x}\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi a^{3}}}e^{-r/a}\right|^{2}\left(r^{2}\sin\theta drd\theta d\phi\right)=\frac{4\pi}{\pi a^{3}}\int_{0}^{x}r^{2}e^{-2r/a}dr.$$ continued ...

Comment: The $\pi$
 's cancelled, so I didn't mention them. Nor did I mention that I meant the complex square of the wave function. If $x=\infty$
  then $P=1$,
  and if $x=0.00000000009$
  then $P=0.66077$.
  I now know my interpretation was right, but my maths was a bit ragged. Thanks.

Comment: @Peter4075 Remember to mention the unit you use, it would be make things clear :)

Comment: Detail is important, that's what science is about. The need for angular integration is shown in the normalisation constant of the wavefunction. This is why I gave you +1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are practically right. The only subtlety is that your wave function argument $\mathbf{r}$ is a *relative* distance between the nucleus and the electron. Nucleus itself "turns around" the atomic center of mass, but with a shorter radius $(m_e/M_N)\cdot a$.

Comment: Well actually you should integrate $|\psi|^2$, not $\psi$.

Comment: @Bzazz: In the original post he integrates a square because $\psi$ is real function in his case.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if you want to know the probability of a particle being in a **sphere**, there should be an integration over a sphere, therefore I would add an additional factor of $4\pi$.

The thing I don't understand is the normalization of the wave function, it  doesn't yield 1 if I integrate it over whole space.

My last issue is just a small one, I wouldn't call this a wave equation, it is already a wave function, the corresponding wave equation is the Schrödinger equation.